# Load data from a plist to two TableViews

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, plist

I am having some trouble to load some data from my property list. Take a look…
This is my `directory.plist`:
[image: directory.plist]

I wanna show all of this, right here on `Main.storyboard`:
[image: Main.storyboard]

But the keys `Position` e `Name` will appear on the first **TableViewController** and the keys `Functionary`, `ImageFace` and `Phone` have to appear on the second **TableViewController**.

To do this, I made this:

1. Added to **AppDelegate** the following:

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "directory", withExtension: "plist"), let array = NSArray(contentsOf: url) as? [[String:Any]] {
           Shared.instance.employees = array.map{Employee(dictionary: $0)}
   }
   return true
   ```
2. Created a `Struct` like this:

   ```
   struct EmployeeDetails {
       let functionary: String
       let imageFace: String
       let phone: String

       init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
           self.functionary = (dictionary["Functionary"] as? String) ?? ""
           self.imageFace = (dictionary["ImageFace"] as? String) ?? ""
           self.phone = (dictionary["Phone"] as? String) ?? ""
       }
   }

   struct Employee {
       let position: String
       let name: String
       let details: [EmployeeDetails] // [String:Any]

       init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
       self.position = (dictionary["Position"] as? String) ?? ""
       self.name = (dictionary["Name"] as? String) ?? ""

       let t = (dictionary["Details"] as? [Any]) ?? []
       self.details = t.map({EmployeeDetails(dictionary: $0 as! [String : Any])})
       }
   }

   struct Shared {
       static var instance = Shared()
       var employees: [Employee] = []
   }
   ```
3. My **First TableViewController**, is like this:

   ```
   class Page1: UITableViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let anEmployee = Shared.instance.employees[1]

       print("Name:", anEmployee.name)
       print("Position:", anEmployee.position)

       anEmployee.details.forEach({

           print("Functionary:", $0.functionary)
           print("ImageFace:", $0.imageFace)
           print("Phone:", $0.phone)
       })
   }

   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 1
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return Shared.instance.employees.count
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1

           cell.nameLabel.text = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row].name
           cell.positionLabel.text = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row].position

           return cell
       }

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if let destination = segue.destination as? Page2,
           let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
           destination.newPage = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row].details[indexPath.row]
           tableView .deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. My **Second TableViewController**, here:

   ```
   var newPage: EmployeeDetails! //recently added

   class Page2: UITableViewController {

   var newPage: EmployeeDetails!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       if let theEmployee = newPage {
           self.title = theEmployee.name
       }
   }

   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       if let theEmployee = newPage {
           return theEmployee.details.count
       }
   return 0
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell2

       if let theEmployee = newPage {

           cell.faceImage.image = theEmployee.details[indexPath.row].imageFace as? UIImage // did not work
           cell.functionary.text = theEmployee.details[indexPath.row].functionary
           cell.phoneLabel.text = theEmployee.details[indexPath.row].phone
       }
       return cell
       }
   }
   ```

When I touch in any item of the first TableViewController, I see the second TableViewController totally empty! And the debug area shows it:

```
2017-03-28 17:16:28.456 plist sample[7138:425253] Unknown class Page2 in Interface Builder file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your plist structure:

```
Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row].details
```

`details` is an Array of Dictionaries. You are treating it as a Dictionary.

Edit: the initial issue was correct... multiple ways to solve it (as you have seen / done). Another option, which may or may not be helpful:

```
struct EmployeeDetails {
    let functionary: String
    let imageFace: String
    let phone: String

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.functionary = (dictionary["Functionary"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.imageFace = (dictionary["ImageFace"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.phone = (dictionary["Phone"] as? String) ?? ""
    }
}
struct Employee {
    let position: String
    let name: String
    let details: [EmployeeDetails] // [String:Any]

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.position = (dictionary["Position"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.name = (dictionary["Name"] as? String) ?? ""

        let t = (dictionary["Details"] as? [Any]) ?? []
        self.details = t.map({EmployeeDetails(dictionary: $0 as! [String : Any])})
    }
}

struct Shared {
    static var instance = Shared()
    var employees: [Employee] = []
}
```

you can then do your original:

```
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "directory", withExtension: "plist"), let array = NSArray(contentsOf: url) as? [[String:Any]] {

        Shared.instance.employees = array.map{Employee(dictionary: $0)}

    }
```

and then access the data via:

```
    let anEmployee = Shared.instance.employees[0]

    print("Name:", anEmployee.name)
    print("Position:", anEmployee.position)

    print("Detail 0 Functionary:", anEmployee.details[0].functionary)
    print("Detail 0 ImageFace:", anEmployee.details[0].imageFace)
    print("Detail 0 Phone:", anEmployee.details[0].phone)

    // or

    anEmployee.details.forEach({

        print("Functionary:", $0.functionary)
        print("ImageFace:", $0.imageFace)
        print("Phone:", $0.phone)

    })
```

just for example.

See https://github.com/DonMag/SWPListData for a working example.

Comment: ummm... ok... did you understand my answer? You are treating `details` like a `Dictionary` when it is an `Array` of Dictionaries. See the EDIT in my answer

Comment: Now I have the following error message: `Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'` on the prints of Functionary and ImageFace.

Comment: I made an edit, now I think it is going to be ok after the `segue`.

Comment: @ArnonRodrigues - looks like you're on your way. I updated my answer, changing your original struct a bit to give you more "consistent" access to the data. May be better, may be not :)

Comment: I am having trouble on segue. I just updated my question (both TableViewControllers). Could you take a look?

Comment: @ArnonRodrigues - you're very close... I went ahead and put up a GItHub repo so you can take a look - much easier than trying to figure out what to explain :)

Comment: it helped a lot!! Thank you so much!!! But the second `TableViewController` is still empty when I choose the **Stile Custom** on `Table View Cell`. (Unfortunately, I have to use the Custom Stile) :-(    ….    Also, I edited the question based on your GitHub repo (except the Stile of `Table View Cell`).

Comment: Based on the debug / error message, it looks like something is not hooked up correctly in your Storyboard. Double-check the Class assigned to each of your UITableViewControllers in Interface Builder. And, if you're seeing the table2 but it's "empty" - does it have the correct number of rows? There too it sounds like a mixup in Storyboard... cell prototype missing an ID maybe?

Comment: :( Nothing! I don't know how to upload a repo on GitHub, so I made it on Mega. Could you take a look? https://mega.nz/#!Ogp0yRBK!_ruUHADk-DLq64_Q8DTpgoO6qVXLYoaVgYysNGKfws0

Comment: Yeah, stuff can get "confused" in IB. Open your Main.storyboard... select the Functionaries scene... Change the Class (under Identity Inspector) from `Page2` to a plain `UITableViewController`... press Command+B to build... Select Functionaries scene again... change the Class back to Page2... run the app, and.... woo hoo?

Comment: man!!! WTF you just did??? You are a genius!!! My last doubt: what do I have to do to the image on Page2 appear? Because you can see I tryed to turn it into a UIImage…

Comment: Assuming you have the images inside your app bundle, and the names match, change that line to: `cell.faceImage.image = UIImage(named: theEmployee.details[indexPath.row].imageFace)`   well, with appropriate error handling, of course.

Comment: thanks bro! All problems solved!! I am trying not to be so newbie! Lol THANKS!!